# How was this picture made?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

On the [wikipedia page for Calabi–Yau manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) there is a picture. I want to learn how to make pictures like this. They claim that it is a hyperplane section of a quintic three-fold but whenever I use computer software to visualize the real points of such a hyperplane section it always looks really boring.

> **Question:**  How was this picture made?

Comment: If you click on the picture there is an information page, saying that it was created in Mathematica by the author, and there is a link.  You could ask the author for the source.